# Is there a common abbreviation for "Hausaufgabe"?

Tags: abbreviation

When writing down homework assignment, anglophones often announce it with "H/W:", "HW:" or "HMW:", because the teacher typically has already started speaking and they don't want to waste time spelling out the entire word "Homework".

Do German students shorten "Hausaufgabe:" similarly? Would they write "H/A:" or "HAG:" or something else?

Comment: My kids use "HA".

Both of them. I consider that common.

Comment: In Austria it's commonly referred to as Hausübung, often abbreviated as HÜ.

Comment: I just used to draw a little home "icon".

Comment: Schrägstriche in Abkürzungen sind mir generell unbekannt. Da Hausaufgabe ein Wort ist gehört das A auch klein geschrieben, aber üblich mag etwas anderes sein.

Comment: The German teachers I met wrote it "H.A", and pronounced each letter separately: " Haa Ahh".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While there is not official abbreviation the common one simply is *HA*. The cool kids of today call them *Hausi*. :)

Comment: Apparantly, cool kids haven’t changed their preferred word in almost twenty years then. (Oh god, I’m old …)